# Elipse not refreshing file name on rename

Tags: eclipse, wildwebdeveloper

I always had problems regarding refresh on Eclipse, but this time it's very annoying.
Nothing is changing on project explorer when I create, rename or copy a file to other dir. I always have to manually call refresh to see the changes.

Anyone has some clue of what might be happening and a way to solve it ?

I use Wild Web Developer to develop in Javascript

Versions: IDE: 4.27, WWD: 1.3.3

**Edit**

As I was preparing to make a video to show what's happening to @nitind, I've gone to another smaller project than my actual one and when I tried it in this project, refresh is working fine.

Then I noticed that this only happens in projects under selected working sets. I have 2 working sets for 2 larger projects with 3 projects each. This only happens in these projects and only when working sets are selected.

**Edit2**

Here's a video of the problem: https://youtu.be/TZm2uUvPH9A

Comment: Have you tried toggling on any of the automatic options from the Workspace preference page?

Comment: @nitind I don't think I understood what you meant. In Eclipse there are 2 preferences page: Project and Window. None of them have a "Workspace" category and the preference tree is enormous. I just can't try all. Or maybe you're refering to something like Working Sets ? Sorry. Can you clarify ?

Comment: Open the Preferences dialog and type in "workspace". You'll see the exact page, under General, in the results.

Comment: In that page I see 2 checks that may be relevant: "Refresh using native hooks or polling" and "Refresh on access". I have checked both and the problem continued. In the subpage Workspace->build there's also "Save automatically before manual build" and "Build automatically". None of those had any effect also. 
I didn't see any other option that may be relevant. If you want I can screenshot those pages.

Comment: I think it would be more useful to understand where your changes that aren't being seen are being made, and how they're connected to the workspace.

Comment: @nitind Please see my edits